# how to limit number of observations per facet using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with thousands of observations and 3 columns. X, Y and facet factor. Can I limit number of observations to 10 for each facet grid by setting some parameter in `ggplot` without managing my data?

```
m1 = d1[,c("ACCOUNT_NAME", "Calculated_Potential", "SEGMENT")]

m1 = m1[order(m1[,"Calculated_Potential"], decreasing = T),]

p <- ggplot(data=m1, aes(x=reorder(ACCOUNT_NAME, Calculated_Potential), 
                         y=Calculated_Potential/10^6)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0)) +
     facet_grid(~ SEGMENT)
```

I would try something like:
`reorder(ACCOUNT_NAME, Calculated_Potential)[1:10]`
but it throws an error. Without it ggplot just plots all the observations.

Is there quick workaround or I need to manage each group manually?

Sample data:

```
m1 = data.frame(ACCOUNT_NAME = stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 10), 
                Calculated_Potential = runif(100, 10^6, 10^7), 
                SEGMENT = round(runif(100, 0, 2)))
```

3 faced plots with all those observations. I'd like to limit them to have only top 10 for each (as like they are sorted).

## Appr. 2

I'm a bit closer using this:

```
# get sorted values for each facet
u = unique(m1$SEGMENT)
seg = NULL
for (i in 1:length(u)) {  #i=1
  m = m1[which(m1$SEGMENT == u[i]),]
  seg[[i]] =  m[order(m[,"Calculated_Potential"], decreasing = T),]
}
seg = lapply(seg, function(x) x[1:10,])

p <- ggplot(data=data.table::rbindlist(seg), aes(x=reorder(ACCOUNT_NAME, Calculated_Potential), y=(Calculated_Potential/10^6))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0)) +
  facet_grid(~ SEGMENT)
```

but now all the data is plotted 30 observations for each facet so there's probably only way to make 3 separate plots not making facets.

Comment: Please take the time and effort to provide sample data.

Comment: what error does it give? Also please include your data and the output that you would like so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't wholly within ggplot, but is pretty compact tidyverse code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

m1 %>% 
  group_by(SEGMENT) %>% 
  top_n(10, Calculated_Potential) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(ACCOUNT_NAME, Calculated_Potential), Calculated_Potential/10^6)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0)) +
    facet_grid(~ SEGMENT, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: You are close but only third group is sorted and have 10 observations. Others are not with less than 10 obs. I mean, this is ok for that representation of random data but not for real. Don't know where's the issue now.

Comment: You might also consider using `sample_n(10)` in place of `top_n` to get a random sample from each `SEGMENT`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I've found the issue - just duplicated values for "ACCOUNT_NAME" caused sorting error. Now it works great.